# How do I convert multiple pictures, in a folder with ITK color map?

Tags: python, opencv, directory, itk, color-mapping

Every time I run my program in the terminal it prints out: 
thumb0496.jpg is not converted
{} is not converted

Whatever I do it never works... I am new to Python and have installed it via Anaconda along with OpenCV, Pip and ITK. I have only been doing this for 4 days and am stuck. Python is my first language also. Why are my code not working?

In case this code looks similar it is. I had to try out with combining some elements. Unfortunately I cannot find the post again. The code was worse before but I (somehow) fixed it. It is just this (new) piece I can't fix on my own!

```
import cv2
import sys
import itk
import os,glob

from os import listdir,makedirs
from os.path import isfile,join
path = '/Users/admin/Desktop/ff'
dstpath = '/Users/admin/Desktop/test'

PixelType = itk.UC
Dimension = 2

ImageType = itk.Image[PixelType, Dimension]

RGBPixelType = itk.RGBPixel[PixelType]
RGBImageType = itk.Image[RGBPixelType, Dimension]

ColormapType = itk.CustomColormapFunction[PixelType, RGBPixelType]
colormap = ColormapType.New()

ColormapFilterType = itk.ScalarToRGBColormapImageFilter[ImageType,RGBImageType]
colormapFilter1 = ColormapFilterType.New()

colormapFilter1.SetInput(reader.GetOutput())
colormapFilter1.SetColormap(colormap)

WriterType = itk.ImageFileWriter[RGBImageType]
writer = WriterType.New()
writer.SetFileName(dstpath)
writer.SetInput(colormapFilter1.GetOutput())

try:
    makedirs(dstpath)
except:
    print ("Directory already exist, images will be written in same folder")
files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path,f))]
for image in files:
    try:
        reader = ReaderType(os.path.join(path,image))
        map = ColormapFilterType(reader, PixelType, RGBImageType, ImageType)
        dstPath = join(dstpath,image)
        cv2.imwrite(dstPath,map)
    except:
        print ("{} is not converted".format(image))
for fil in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    try:
        img = ReaderType(os.path.join(path,fil))
        map_imag = ColormapType(img, PixelType, RGBImageType,ImageType)
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dstpath,fil),map_image)
    except:
        print('{} is not converted')
```

Comment: There are many problems with your piece of code. You did not define `ReaderType`, but you are trying to use it. You created an ITK writer, but you are trying to write the images using OpenCV. That will not work - only ITK writers can write ITK images. For what you are trying to do you don't need OpenCV. And since I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, you might want to look into LabelToRGBImageFilter instead of ScalarToRGBColormapImageFilter + CustomColormapFunction.

Comment: Thanks! So I can't combine cv2 with itk, good to know! I have redefined ReaderType to itk.ImageFileReader and still no change... When i write writer.Update() it gives me this error: "You probably failed to set a file suffix, or det the suffix to an unsupported type." What is the ITK versions of cv2.imwrite and cv2.imread??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start from a working example, and gradually change it to suit your needs? Examples can be found in the [quick-start guide](https://itkpythonpackage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Quick_start_guide.html) and this blog [post](https://blog.kitware.com/itk-python-image-pixel-types/).